# Ajax Jquery with symfony3

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

> i don't know what is wrong with this code, no errors but it doesn't work .
>   what i want is when i click on a table row, a textarea should appear containing >all informations[web page][1] . 
>   *this is the twig file:
>   1. the script

```
<script>
    function detailFunction() {
    $('#ligneSelectionnee').click(function () {

        id=$(this).val();


        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'http://localhost/randonneeweb/web/app_dev.php/recDetailAjax',
            dataType:"json",
            data:{id:id},
            success : function (response) {
                if (response!=null){
                    document.getElementById('nothing').style.display="none";
                    document.querySelector("#zoneDetail").innerHTML=response.view;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById('nothing').style.display="block";
                }

            }
        })

    })}
</script>
```

> 2. the table row which should be selected

```
<tbody>
        {% for m in reclamations %}

            <tr id="ligneSelectionnee" value="{{ m.idreclamation }}" onclick="detailFunction()">
                <td> {{ m.dateReclamation|date('Y-m-d') }}</td>
                <td> {{ m.typereclamation }}</td>
                <td> {{ m.sujetreclamation}}</td>
                <td> {{ m.message }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

> 3. the div where the details should appear

```
<div id="zoneDetail" style="margin-right: 20em">

    </div>
```

> **this is the function in the controller:

```
public function afficherDetailsAction(Request $request)
{echo "hellooo";
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $id=$request->get('id');
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $reclamations=$em->getRepository('RandoPlusRandoBundle:Reclamation')->findBy(array('idreclamation'=>$id));
        dump($reclamations);
        if($reclamations!=null)
        {
            return new JsonResponse(
            ['view'=>$this->renderView('RandoPlusRandoBundle:Reclamation:detailAjax.html.twig',array('detail'=>$reclamations))],200
            );
        }
    }
    return new Response(null);
}
```

> ***the routing for the Ajax Function:

```
recDetailAjax:
path:     /recDetailAjax
defaults: { _controller: RandoPlusRandoBundle:Reclamation:afficherDetails }
```

> ****and finally the twig used by Ajax to load details:

```
<label>Description</label></br><textarea>Date : {{ detail.dateReclamation }}</br>type:{{ detail.typereclamation }}</br>Sujet:{{ detail.sujetreclamation }}</br>Message:{{ detail.message }}</textarea>
```

Comment: In your first javascript function, just under id=$(this).val(); add alert(id); to make sure you are getting a valid id. If that is broken then nothing else will work. I haven't analyzed remainder of your code, but start with the basics and build from there.

Comment: i chaged id = $ (this) .val () verser id = $ (this) .attr ( 'Valeur') et i loggedit Dans la console, et je reçois la bonne Valeur, le Problème Que la Maintenant me consoler this montrer erreur 500 (du serveur erreur interne) i think the probleme comes from the routing , but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: i fixed the routing the path should end with / now the url is found but there's an other problem :                                                 recDetailAjax:
    path:     /recDetailAjax/
    defaults: { _controller: RandoPlusRandoBundle:Reclamation:afficherDetails }

Comment: i added  the function error as a parameter in $.ajax , and i got an error , i don't know the origin of this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**detailAjax.html.twig** is not strict json out but your response is json. you have to change it.

you can use browser consoles network sections when you try ajax. There are details about request in this tool.